# Omniauth and Twitter gems incompatible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I'm having an issue trying to use the latest Twitter gem (1.7.1) with the latest Omniauth (0.2.6). Here's one error, though it looks like depending on the order of gems in my Gemfile I also see issues with faraday versions.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_xml":

```
In Gemfile:
  omniauth (= 0.2.6) depends on
    multi_xml (~> 0.2.2)

  twitter (= 1.7.1) depends on
    multi_xml (0.3.0)
```

Any suggestions? Note:

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I fixed it by requiring the latest versions from github.

```
#Social integration
gem 'twitter', :git => "https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter.git" 
gem 'omniauth', :git => "git://github.com/intridea/omniauth.git", :branch => "3-0-stable"
```